# PHP POST and file upload size limit for 500 bytes

Tags: apache-2.2, php, performance, upload

I have a weird problem, I try to post contents or upload files by php to my server (I have access to the server settings).

After submitting the form it sleeps for a while then shows a page loading error. I tried different contents and files with different sizes and found that it only can post/upload contents/files with size bellow 530 bytes! (approximately)

**upload_max_filesize** is 2M
**post_max_size** is 8M

You can see other setting via

```
http://78.39.102.77/phpinfo.php
```

I am connected to the internet via a PPPoE connection. before I had problem in FTP and I solve that problem by setting MTU of the server to 1460
however now even changing MTU doesnt help

from the link below you can test this problem via a test page I created.
please tell me if it happens on your computer or not

```
http://78.39.102.77/test3.php
```

I can upload/post to the other sites

please Help!

P.S. because the address includes IP I couldn't put the link here